# select last visible field when function is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, visible

This is my problem:

We have 5 input fields with the same class name, for example `class="inputfield"`. By default, when the page is loaded, you only see the first. Next to the field you have a button to show the second field. When you click on it, the function `showNext()` is used and you will see the second field with next to it again a button to show the 3rd field etc...

What do I want to do? I have to get the last visible input field with `class="inputfield"`.

I've already found the function last() and `:visible`, but when I click on the button to show the next input field, the first is still the last because I don't know how to refresh my code.

What I want to do is, every time the function `showNext` is called, I need to run my code so I alway have the last visible input field. I can't add code in `showNext()` so I need a `listener` and my own code to select the last visible input field.

With my code I want to add a value in the input field when the user clicks on another button that I will display. But I always need to add it to the last visible input field, that's why I need to know what the last visible field is...

**Extra info**:
The non visible fields are already in the code with display:none.
What I tried is:

1. when I only use the `$(".inputfield").last()` I get the last field, but the invisible one...
2. with `$(".inputfield:visible")` it's always the first that is "selected". Even if the second is now visible

Is this possible?

Printscreen of my problem:
I select it with

```
$(".inputfield:visible").last().css("border", "2px solid #990000");
```

[image]

Edit:
I think I found a way around for my problem so I always have the last visible field. Tnx for the help.

Comment: What's your (relevant) minimal code? Note to answerers: could you ***read*** the question, before suggesting `last()` or `:last`?

Comment: Just a note, given the lack of code (HTML, the relevant JavaScript/jQuery) I'm voting to close as "off-topic."

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.__ Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element with classname `'inputfield'`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield');
var lastInput = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
```

To get the last *visible* element with classname `'inputfield'`, it's easier to use jQuery:

```
var inputs = $('.inputfield:visible').last();
```

Comment: The *last visible `input`...*

Comment: when I only use the $(".inputfield:visible").last() I get the last field, but the invisible one...

Comment: @DavidThomas: Whoops, missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: $('.inputfield:visible').last(); Is not working. See point (2) in my question. it's always the first that is "selected". I need to refresh the $('.inputfield:visible').last();

Comment: That's weird. How are you changing their visibility?

Comment: @endeka: you know what would help us to work this out? Some code showing what you're doing. And, possibly, a live demo.

Comment: with the button next to the visible input field, with a javascript function

Comment: @endeka: If a programmer asks you _"How do you do X"_, the programmer expects to be answered in code. As in, _literally_, how are you making them visible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isin't that clear, but from what I understand, you are trying to access the last element that was visible after `showNext` is called.

Knowing that the last visible input is the input that precedes the currenlty visible one, you could use that logic to know what was the last visible input once `showNext` is called.

However, you can also simply retrieve the currently visible element before calling on `showNext`.

```
var $lastVisible = $('.inputfield:visible').last();

showNext();
```

Note that you can also use the same logic to get the last field that was made visible after `showNext` was called if you inverse the statements.

Comment: I already suggested `$('.inputfield:visible').last()`, but apparently, that isn't working...